# Бег по стенам на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу реализовать в своей игре на Unity возможность горизонтального бега по стенам. Может знает кто как можно это реализовать? Хочу чтоб сначало игрок немного поднимался вверх, а потом постепенно опускаться вниз, как это в общем то было в Принце Персии. Я старался реализовать с помощью controller.Move,но не могу разобраться с самим алгоритмом задуманного движения.

Comment: Движение вдоль нормали поверхности не для начинающего уровня

Comment: Yaroslav, понимаю, но всеравно интересно как это делается)

Comment: "unity wall run" в гугле поможет. Лично у меня первый же результат привел к туториалу от самих Unity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOVtucXxb1E где можно скачать ссорцы и буквально взять готовый скрипт.

Comment: @Andrew, большое спасибо!